# Searching a maptree of arrayLists

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, treemap

I have a treemap of arrayLists.  I need to check each list for matching elements. My code works, except it's only checking the arrays against ones <= itself. The other arrays track fine. I'd imagine it's a stupid error I'm missing, but..

```
            ArrayList<Integer> currentArray;
            ArrayList<Integer> compareArray;

            //Setting user friend list

              //cycle users "i"
              for(int i = 1; i <= treemap.size(); i++){
                currentArray = treemap.get(i);

                  //cycle user "k"
                    for(int k=1; k <= treemap.size(); k++){
                      //if(i!=k){  Put back in once working
                        compareArray = treemap.get(k);
                        //cylce "k"s movie list
                        for(int l=0; l < compareArray.size(); l++){
                          if(currentArray.contains(compareArray.get(l))){
                            if (treemap2.containsKey(i)){
                              ArrayList<Integer> list3 = treemap2.get(i);
                              list3.add(k);
                              treemap2.remove(i);
                              treemap2.put(i, list3);
                            }
                            if (!treemap2.containsKey(i)){
                              ArrayList<Integer> list4 =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
                              list4.add(k);
                              treemap2.put(i, list4);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    }
              }
            //Create string of friends
            for(ArrayList<Integer>  x: treemap2.values()){
              str2 = Integer.toString(x.get(0));
              for (int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++) 
              {
                  str2 = str2 + "," + Integer.toString(x.get(i)) ;
              }      
            }

            context.write(key, new Text(str2));
```

I still need to correct the key, that's easy and not getting used in the final program either way.

I should be getting
1   1,1,1,2,2
2   1,1,2,2,2
3   2,3,3,3

Instead I'm getting
1   1,1,1
2   1,1,2,2,2
3   2,3,3,3

Either way, thank you in advance.
Side note, doing the below gets me exactly what I want... Except it leaves out the last array....!!

```
        //cycle current array "i"
        for(int i = 1; i < treemap.size(); i++){
          currentArray = treemap.get(i);
            //cycle compare array "k"
              for(int k=1; k <= treemap.size(); k++){
                if(i!=k){   //
                  compareArray = treemap.get(k);
                  //cylce array element in compare "l"
                  for(int l=0; l < compareArray.size(); l++){
                    if(currentArray.contains(compareArray.get(l))){
                      if (treemap2.containsKey(i)){
                        ArrayList<String> list3 = treemap2.get(i);
                        list3.add(k+":"+compareArray.get(l));
                        treemap2.remove(i);
                        treemap2.put(i, list3);
                      }
                      if (!treemap2.containsKey(i)){
                        ArrayList<String> list4 =  new ArrayList<String>();
                        list4.add(k+":"+compareArray.get(l));
                        treemap2.put(i, list4);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
        }




1   2105
1   1953
1   1339
2   2105
2   1321
2   1339
3   1321
3   1544
3   1222
```

Comment: I would step through this with my debugger if it was complete, but it's missing code at the beginning and end.  For example, I can't see how treemap is declared.  Can you post the full code listing?

Comment: I added it, but.. It's designed to run for hadoop.

Comment: Could you also give me the list of values in each array of your treemap that you used for your test?

Comment: The actual data I have is mcuh bigger, but the massively truncated data is:
1 2105
1 1953
1 1339
2 2105
2 1321
2 1339
3 1321
3 1544
3 1222

Comment: I realize that :) just enough to validate expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in a car and doing my best to add it. Its up there as part of code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190562/discussion-between-don-and-hooch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit uncertain about some of your variable and data definitions because there was some difference between the two postings.  However, I created a stand-alone Java program that isolates your algorithm and uses mock data to test it.  The entire program is below it's pretty small.

This would be my general approach to use a mix of trace and a debugger breakpoint to be able to see the results and inspect all variables at key points.

You could correct any incorrect assumptions I made about data types.

I hope this helps.

```
package com.example.hadoop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 * I took your original code posting (which differs somewhat from the second
 * snippet) and I converted it into a stand alone Java program with mock test
 * data.
 * 
 * This program would be my starting point to finding the logic error.
 * 
 * My approach was to (1) isolate your algorithm, (2) mock out a minimal set of
 * input data to test just the algorithm, and (3) step through with the debugger
 * and/or use some trace statements.
 * 
 * I made assumptions about variable definitions based on the code and
 * information provided since I could not see all the actual definitions.
 * 
 * Some of your data types differ between your two code fragments so I was a bit
 * unsure about that.
 * 
 * I may be wrong on some of the variable definitions so modify these as needed.
 * 
 * You mentioned that:
 * 
 * Expected result: 1 1,1,1,2,2 2 1,1,2,2,2 3 2,3,3,3
 * 
 * Actual result: 1 1,1,1 2 1,1,2,2,2 3 2,3,3,3
 * 
 * Massively truncated test data: 1 2105 1 1953 1 1339 2 2105 2 1321 2 1339 3
 * 1321 3 1544 3 1222
 */
public class HadoopTestApp {

    /*
     * Mock test variables.
     */
    ArrayList<Integer> datalist1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2105, 1953, 1339));
    ArrayList<Integer> datalist2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2105, 1321, 1339));
    ArrayList<Integer> datalist3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1321, 1544, 1222));
    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> treemap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> treemap2 = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    String str2 = "";

    /**
     * Use the default constructor to complete the initialization of mock test
     * variables.
     */
    public HadoopTestApp() {

        treemap.put(1, datalist1);
        treemap.put(2, datalist2);
        treemap.put(3, datalist3);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap the test.
     * 
     * @param args Command line arguments are not currently used.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HadoopTestApp().run(args);
    }

    /**
     * If you prefer to trace variables manually. Or you can set some breakpoints
     * and inspect variables in the debugger.
     */
    public void doTrace(String label, Object o) {
        System.out.print(label + ": ");
        System.out.println(o);
    }

    /**
     * Run the test of Hooch's algorithm.
     * 
     * @param args Command line arguments are not currently used.
     */
    public void run(String[] args) {

        doTrace("treemap", treemap); // NEW

        ArrayList<Integer> currentArray;
        ArrayList<Integer> compareArray;

        // Setting user friend list

        // cycle users "i"
        for (int i = 1; i <= treemap.size(); i++) {
            currentArray = treemap.get(i);

            // cycle user "k"
            for (int k = 1; k <= treemap.size(); k++) {
                // if(i!=k){ Put back in once working
                compareArray = treemap.get(k);
                // cylce "k"s movie list
                for (int l = 0; l < compareArray.size(); l++) {
                    if (currentArray.contains(compareArray.get(l))) {
                        // NEW I set a debugger breakpoint on this line to inspect all variables
                        if (treemap2.containsKey(i)) {
                            ArrayList<Integer> list3 = treemap2.get(i);
                            list3.add(k);
                            treemap2.remove(i);
                            treemap2.put(i, list3);
                            doTrace("contains key, treemap2", treemap2); // NEW
                        }
                        if (!treemap2.containsKey(i)) {
                            ArrayList<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            list4.add(k);
                            treemap2.put(i, list4);
                            doTrace("does not contain key, treemap2", treemap2); // NEW
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Create string of friends
        for (ArrayList<Integer> x : treemap2.values()) {
            str2 = Integer.toString(x.get(0));
            for (int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++) {
                str2 = str2 + "," + Integer.toString(x.get(i));
            }
            doTrace("in loop str2", str2); // NEW
        }

        // context.write(key, new Text(str2));
        doTrace("context.write str2", str2); // NEW

    }

}
```

Comment: So the only real difference here is the "i <= treemap.size()" vs the "i <treemap.size()" And while I agree that's how it *should be* it doesn't work.  With your example it only searches the array to itself. So 1[1], 2[1,2], 3[1,2,3].
with "i<" I get 1[1,2,3], 2[1,2,3], 3 never runs..

Comment: My example is just a wrapper around the code of your original question and the idea is to have a starting point to clarify my assumptions about the data types and inputs.  It's not the fix, it would just be my approach to identify where the conditional logic does not work as intended, by using a mix of trace and debug breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah, the algorithm was right. It's just having issues printing it out. Still having the issue, but much closer. Thanks.